# Setting up projects with IvyDE

Tags: eclipse, ivy, ivyde

Are there any good sample projects with IvyDE or tutorials on setting up projects with IvyDE in Eclipse?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [ivyde Documentation](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/history/latest-milestone/index.html) should help.

It has an installation guide.

Basically you just have to:

1. Install the plugin
2. Point the settings to your ivysettings.xml (if you have one)
3. Write the ivy.xml for your project
4. Add the IVY-Classpath-Container for your project

Answer (score 18):

1. Add the plugin to Eclipse.
2. Right click project and Create new ivy.xml file.
3. Search your dependencies on the [maven repo](http://mvnrepository.com) and add it to your ivy file.
4. Right click ivy file add select add ivy library. It will automatically perform ivy resolve and add dependencies to you ivy library.

You can find detailed information with some screenshots in [Installing and using Apache Ivy as dependency manager](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2014/04/installing-and-using-apache-ivy-as.html).

PS: Above link is to my personal blog that I write.

Comment: That step number 4 is the key and much better than step 4 of the accepted solution!

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is too old to answer. But this may help few developers like me. [Refer this PDF document - ApacheIvyBeginners Guide](http://web.archive.org/web/20150419114822/http://saharabear.com/weblog/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/ApacheIvyBeginnersGuide.pdf). Its awesome, just of 30 pages.